# In PHP 2<<3 returns 16 and 3 << 2 returns 12 Can some one explain this please

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo 2<<3; //Output 16 
echo '---';
echo 3<<2; //Output 12 
?>
```

Tried to find out logic. But its ends up in vain!! Can someone explain it please

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: 2 << 3 Shift left Shift the bits of $2 $3 steps to the left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<<` operator is a [bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). This basically means the numbers are treated as binary numbers, and the interaction is about moving bits around.

So let's have a look at the numbers and the operations:

First, `2 << 3`

```
0b000010 // 2 in binary
0b010000 // move the bits three left, we get 16
```

Then `3 << 2`

```
0b000011 // 3 in binary
0b001100 // move the bits two left, we get 12
```

From the manual page linked above:

> Shift the bits of `$a` `$b` steps to the left (each step means "multiply by two")

So `3<<2` in effect means `3*(2^2)`, while `2<<3` means `2*(2^3)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `<<` operator is bitwise left shift.

Let's write the numbers in their binary representation

```
0000 0010 // 2
0000 0011 // 3
```

And then shift them by 3 and 2 respectively:

```
0001 0000 // 16
0000 1100 // 12
```

Comment: Why do you need my email …?

Answer (score 0):

```
      2 = 0b10
  0b100 = 4
 0b1000 = 8
0b10000 = 16

     3 = 0b11
 0b110 = 6
0b1100 = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

The fist operator (<<) is the bitwise shift operator, specifically the left-shift operator. It takes the left hand argument and shifts the binary representation to the left by the number of bits specified by the right argument. Right-shift (>>) does the same but to the right. Read more about it here http://php.net/language.operators.bitwise